# What is current status of Trump's Carroll II payment?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, president

In 2023 a court/jury ruled that Trump should pay $5 million dollars to EJ Carroll.  I understand he has [submitted that money](https://www.reuters.com/legal/trump-sets-aside-money-while-he-appeals-e-jean-carrolls-5-million-verdict-2023-06-23/) to the court which is holding it pending an appeal. But I can find no details of the current status of the appeal itself.

The original case was Carroll v Trump, U.S. District Court, Southern District of New York, No. 22-10016. It is often known as Carroll II.

This answer from [September 2023](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/95371/10883) points to a claim of immunity. This has already been [rejected by the appeals court](https://www.reuters.com/legal/court-rejects-donald-trumps-request-immunity-e-jean-carrolls-defamation-suit-2023-12-13/) in December 2023.  The [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national-security/2024/01/28/trump-trials-tracker-latest-news/) (29 January 2024) says:

> Q: Has Trump already paid the $5 million he owes Carroll?  [...]

> A: Trump is
> appealing that first $5 million jury verdict, but per standard court
> practice, he has already put about $5.5 million into an escrow account
> so it is available once the appeal is decided.

Has Trump submitted a motion appealing the Appeals court ruling and is it that that is stopping him from having to pay Carroll? Are there any details on the current status ? Has the Supreme court granted cert?  Is there another appeal that is holding back the payment?  Perhaps most importantly, when is Carroll likely to receive payment assuming Trump loses all the appeals?

Comment: Appealing an appeals court ruling?  Appeals are final unless SCOTUS grants certiorari - which is entirely discretionary.

Comment: @Trish Yes. But I can't tell whether a submission has been made to SCOTUS or if SCOTUS has granted cert. Maybe there could also be an en banc hearing first?  I feel the information should be available online but I am not sure where.

Comment: First of all, you'd look for the case number....

Comment: @Trish The original case is Carroll v Trump, U.S. District Court, Southern District of New York, No. 22-10016 .  I did try to search with that but I didn't manage to find any information about the current status.

Comment: **Caroll II** is 22-cv-10016(LAK) (S.D.N.Y. Mar. 28, 2023) - https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/65895581/carroll-v-trump/ - see Docket entry 96, which points out that it is Caroll II

Comment: [See Complaint, Carroll v. Trump, No. 22-cv-10016
(“Carroll II”) (S.D.N.Y. Nov. 24, 2022). In May 2023, the Carroll II jury awarded
Plaintiff $5 million in damages. The verdict is the subject of a separate appeal
currently pending before this Court. See Carroll II, appeal docketed, No. 23-793 (2d
Cir. May 11, 2023).](https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/9451621/carroll-v-trump/)

Comment: There's also docket [23-1146-cv](https://www.courtlistener.com/docket/67689814/carroll-v-trump/) that is indicates a Judgement Mandate on January 16th... Oh, YES, that docket has it: 141

Jan 3, 2024

ORDER, dated 01/03/2024, denying application contained within the pending petition for rehearing en banc to stay the district court proceedings, by JAC, DC, MAK, FILED.[3601639] [23-1045, 23-1146] [Entered: 01/03/2024 04:19 PM]

Comment: @Trish It is confusing as https://storage.courtlistener.com/pdf/2023/12/13/carroll_v._trump.pdf says "Finally, we REMAND the case to the District Court for further
proceedings consistent with this opinion."  But, overall is the status that there is some time for Trump to decide whether he wants to appeal to SCOTUS?

Comment: That document is, afaik, the appellate court's final denial of the immunity defense. If there was a scotus appeal would be at... uh....

Comment: The only SCOTUS 2023 term case with cert and Trump was Trump v Anderson https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/23grantednotedlist.pdf

Comment: And not a single case in 2024 with Trump in it yet https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/24grantednotedlist.pdf

Comment: @Trish Could have Trump have filed a petition for cert?  And if not, is there a time limit to do so?

Comment: Could have? Possibly. The time limit is 90 days after the final judgement of the appalate court. So first Trump would have to appeal Carroll I.

Comment: @Trish I just meant, would the filing be visible to us if he had filed it. Why would he have to appeal Carroll I first?

Comment: @Trish Does Trump have to at least file an attention to appeal more quickly than 90 days? Otherwise it seems like the enforcement of all appeal court rulings would be delayed by 90 days simply by doing nothing.

Comment: @Trish "Appeals are final unless SCOTUS grants certiorari" not quite.  A ruling by a three-judge panel of an appeals court can be reheard by the entire court _en banc._

Comment: @phoog In this case that option was rejected. This question is, what is happening now?